# Slick Slider - Increase duration time between slides

Tags: javascript, animation, slider, slick.js

this should be very straight forward but it is defeating me. See my slick slider here:

https://www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/uni-relations/gallery-01.html

**I simply want to increase the time the user has to read the text on every slide. It seems to be about 2.5 seconds now. I want to increase it to about 6 seconds.**

In this file below I have tried increasing the autoplayTimeout and autoplaySpeed values but it makes no difference:

https://www.ucd.ie/research/sandbox/uni-relations/slick.js

Any help for a javascript novice much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`autoplaySpeed` is definitely the parameter that you want to adjust. You generally do not want to change the default values directly in the Slick library.  Instead you should set overriding values for each slideshow at the time you add Slick to an element on your page.

The code which is adding Slick to each element having class `slider__study` is in https://www.ucd.ie/graduatestudies/t4media/ucd-masters-2018.js (line 146) and looks like this:

```
$('.slider__study').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000
});
```

This is where you would set your overriding `autoplaySpeed` (and any other overrides).